# How to make subplots from multiple files? Python matplot lib

Tags: python, file, matplotlib, graph

I'm a student researcher who's running simulations on exoplanets to determine if they might be viable for life. The software I'm using, outputs a file with several columns of various types of data. So far, I've written a python script that goes through one file and grabs two columns of data. In this case, time and global temperature of the planet.

What I want to do is:

1. Write a python script that goes through multiple files, and grabs the same two columns that my current script does.
2. Then, I want to create subplots of all these files

The things that will stay consistent across all of the files, is the fact that times doesn't change, the x axis will always be time (from 0 to 1 million years). The y axis values will changes across simulations though.

This is what I got so far for my code:

```
import math as m
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np



## Set datafile equal to the file I plan on using for data, and then open it
datafile = r"C:\Users\sasuk\OneDrive\Desktop\GJ 229 Planet Data\Gj 229 b - [SemiMajor 0.867][Ecc][Mass][Luminosity]\solarsys.Earth.forward"
file = open(datafile, "r")

# Create two empty arrays for my x and y axis of my graphs
years = [ ]
GlobalT = [ ]

# A for loop that looks in my file, and grabs only the 1st and 8th column adding them to the respective arrays
for line in file:
    data = line.split(' ')
    years.append(float(data[0]))
    GlobalT.append(float(data[7]))

# Close the file
file.close()


# Plot my graph
fig = plt.matplotlib.pyplot.gcf()

plt.plot(years, GlobalT)
plt.title('Global Temperature of GJ 229 b over time')
fig.set_size_inches(10, 6, forward=True)
plt.figtext(0.5, 0.0002, "This shows the global temperature of GJ 229 b when it's semi-major axis is 0.929 au, \n"
                         " and it's actual mass relative to the sun (~8 Earth Masses)", wrap=True, horizontalalignment='center', fontsize=12)
plt.xlabel(" Years ")
plt.ylabel("Global Temp")

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest thing to do is to turn your code for one file into a function, and then call it in a loop that iterates over the files.

```
from pathlib import Path


def parse_datafile(pth):
    """Parses datafile"""
    results = []
    with pth.open('r') as f:
        for line in f:
            data = line.split(' ')
            results.append({'f': pth.stem,
                            'y': data[0],
                            't': data[7]}) 
    return results

basedir = Path(r'C:\Users\sasuk\OneDrive\Desktop\GJ 229 Planet Data\Gj 229 b - [SemiMajor 0.867][Ecc][Mass][Luminosity]')

# assuming you want to parse all files in directory
# if not, can change glob string for files you want
all_results = [parse_datafile(pth) for pth in basedir.glob('*')]

df = pd.DataFrame(all_results)

df['y'] = pd.to_numeric(df['y'], errors='coerce')
df['t'] = pd.to_numeric(df['t'], errors='coerce')
```

This will give you a dataframe with three columns - f (the filename), y (the year), and t (the temperature). You then have to convert y and t to numeric dtypes. This will be faster and handle errors more gracefully than your code, which will raise an error with any malformed data.

You can further manipulate this as needed to generate your plots. Definitely check if there are any NaN values and address them accordingly, either by dropping those rows or using fillna.

Comment: Okay, interesting. So where would I put your code? Would that replace my for loop and everything that come before I call my plt.plot() function?